# Changing tab bar item image and text color iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Here is my tab bar:

[image]

The following image shows the program being run and the "NEWS" item selected:

[image]

It is clear the bar tint color is working fine as I want !

But the tintColor only affects the image and not the text.

Also, when the an item is selected (as seen above, news) the item color goes blue! How do I prevent this from happening? I want it to stay white.

Why is the text changing to a white color when selected but not when it is unselected?

I basically want the item color and text color to be white all the time.

How do I achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Does it require swift code for each individual item?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you create images for all icons white and gray and you can change whenever its needed.

Comment: The image turns blue when selected and the text is white when not selected. I don't know why... this is my problem

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From UITabBarItem class docs:

> By default, the actual unselected and selected images are
>   automatically created from the alpha values in the source images. To
>   prevent system coloring, provide images with
>   UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

The clue is not whether you use UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal, the important thing is when to use it.

To prevent the grey color for unselected items, you will just need to prevent the system colouring for the unselected image. Here is how to do this:

```
var firstViewController:UIViewController = UIViewController()
// The following statement is what you need
var customTabBarItem:UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"))
firstViewController.tabBarItem = customTabBarItem
```

As you can see, I asked iOS to apply the original color (white, yellow, red, whatever) of the image ONLY for the UNSELECTED state, and leave the image as it is for the SELECTED state.

Also, you may need to add a tint color for the tab bar in order to apply a different color for the SELECTED state (instead of the default iOS blue color). As per your screenshot above, you are applying white color for the selected state:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to create a class corresponding to the Tab Bar to input this code?

Comment: @GregoryPeck in AppDelegate or Create you own TabBarClass but don't forget to assign it via Interface Builder

Comment: I have the tintColor set above as you can see. Also, I have set rendering as Original Image, see Edit.

Comment: And where do I put the code `firstViewController.tabBarItem = customTabBarItem`

Comment: @GregoryPeck You have to put it in the TabBarClass

Comment: @GregoryPeck And Yes your Edit is Right !

Comment: Sorry about all the questions, but Im unsure about how to create the Tab Bar class. i.e- `TabBarClass: ??, ??` and I can't seem to connect it with my tab bar. Is it the tab bar or tab bar controller I must connect it to?

Comment: Hi, I'm also having issues implementing this code. I've tried to make a subclass of `UITabBar` and `UITabBarITem`, but had no luck. Can anyone give more details about where to put this code and how to make it work?

Comment: yes changing the setting on the asset is the way to do this

Answer (score 79):

**Swift 3**

I did it by creating a custom tabbar controller and added this code inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
    if let count = self.tabBar.items?.count {
        for i in 0...(count-1) {
            let imageNameForSelectedState   = arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState[i]
            let imageNameForUnselectedState = arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState[i]

            self.tabBar.items?[i].selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageNameForSelectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            self.tabBar.items?[i].image = UIImage(named: imageNameForUnselectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }

    let selectedColor   = UIColor(red: 246.0/255.0, green: 155.0/255.0, blue: 13.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let unselectedColor = UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 224.0/255.0, blue: 223.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: unselectedColor], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedColor], for: .selected)
```

It worked for me!

[image]

Comment: In Swift 4, "NSForegroundColorAttributeName" has been renamed to "NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor".

Comment: ... and in Swift4.2, "NSAttributedStringKey" has been renamed to "NSAttributedString.Key".

Answer (score 60):

#### Swift

---

**For Image:**

```
custom.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "tab_icon_normal"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab_icon_selected"))
```

---

**For Text:**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
    
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 55):

## Swift 5 and Xcode 13

The solution that worked for me:

1. **Image setup** - from the storyboard set Bar Item Image and Selected Image. To remove the tint overlay on the images go to Assets catalog, select the image and change its rendering mode like this:

[image: image render mode]

This will prevent the Tab bar component from setting its default image tint.

2. **Text** - here I created a simple UITabBarController subclass and in its viewDidLoad method I customized the default and selected text color like this:

   ```
    class HomeTabBarController: UITabBarController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [HomeTabBarController.self])
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: .black], for: .normal)
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: .red], for: .selected)
        }
    }
   ```

Just set this class as your Tab bar controller custom class in identity inspector in IB.

Voila! That's it.

**iOS 13 Update**:

**+ iOS 15 / Xcode 13 Update**:

Add this to your setup for iOS 13 and iOS 15:
Update **23/09/2022** for strange behaviour on iOS 15 when built on Xcode 13 when the tab bar is missing:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .red]
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    // Update for iOS 15, Xcode 13
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you want to do it using the inspector! Thanks so much this solved my issue

Comment: Thanks, your iOS 13 update really helped me. I had a strange bug where the selected item text colour was correct when the tabbar is initially created, but after the tabbar is hidden and reappears (e.g. presenting full screen modal then dismissing it), changing tabs would reset the selected item text colour to the tint colour. Adding the iOS 13 setup fixed it.

Comment: change the rendering mode works for me.

Answer (score 20):

Swift 4: In your UITabBarController change it by this code

```
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .black
```

Comment: Objective-C `self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"ColorName"];`

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 3**

This worked for me (referring to set tabBarItems image colors):

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = ThemeColor.Blue

if let items = tabBarController.tabBar.items {
        let tabBarImages = getTabBarImages() // tabBarImages: [UIImage]
        for i in 0..<items.count {
            let tabBarItem = items[i]
            let tabBarImage = tabBarImages[i]
            tabBarItem.image = tabBarImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            tabBarItem.selectedImage = tabBarImage
        }
    }
```

I have noticed that if you set image with rendering mode = .alwaysOriginal, the UITabBar.tintColor doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 17):

I know here are lots of answers but I can't find an easy and valid copy/paste answer for **Swift 4.2/ Swift 5.1**

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Or use `UITabBar.appearances()` instead of `tabBarController?.tabBar` like this:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Images have to be [UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagerenderingmode?language=objc)

Comment: Finally a simple solution!

Comment: appearance instead of appearances

Answer (score 12):

### Swift 3

First of all, make sure you have added the BOOLEAN key "View controller-based status bar appearance" to Info.plist, and set the value to "NO".

**Appdelegate.swift**

Insert code somewhere after "launchOptions:[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {"

1. Change the color of the tab bar itself with RGB color value:

`UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.145, green: 0.592, blue: 0.804, alpha: 1.00)`

OR one of the default UI colors:

`UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white)`

---

2. Change the text color of the tab items:

**The selected item**

`UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .selected)`

**The inactive items**

`UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black], for: .normal)`

3. To change the color of the image, I believe the easiest approach is to make to separate images, one for each state.

If you don´t make the icons from scratch, alternating black and white versions are relatively easy to make in Photoshop.

---

**Adobe Photoshop (almost any version will do)**

Make sure your icon image has transparent background, and the icon itself is solid black (or close).

Open the image file, save it under a different file name (e.g. exampleFilename-Inverted.png)

In the "Adjustments" submenu on the "Image" menu:

Click "Invert"

You now have a negative of your original icon.

In XCode, set one of the images as "Selected Image" under the Tab Bar Properties in your storyboard, and specify the "inactive" version under "Bar Item" image.

Ta-Da

Comment: For your 3rd point you can change it without using photoshop as: `UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha, the tintcolor works for selected state of the tabbar icon. But for unselected state icon color (on < iOS10), is there a similar property that can be changed?

Answer (score 10):

Try add it on **AppDelegate.swift** (inside **application** method):

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// For WHITE color: 
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Tab bar icon selected color
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    // For WHITE color: UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    return true
}
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

My english is so bad! I'm sorry! :-)

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 5 ioS 13.2** things have changed with TabBar styling, below code work 100%, tested out.

Add the below code in your **UITabBarController** class.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white

        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)

        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)

        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
 }

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func setTabBarItemColors(_ itemAppearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
    itemAppearance.normal.iconColor = .lightGray
    itemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]

    itemAppearance.selected.iconColor = .white
    itemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(_ itemAppearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
    //Adjust the badge position as well as set its color
    itemAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .orange
    itemAppearance.normal.badgeTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    itemAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 1, vertical: -1)
}
```

Comment: I apply your way but it doesn't work with iOS 15. I cannot change the badge color or attribute. Have you resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

I created the tabbar class file and wrote the following code

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true

let selectedColor   = UIColor.red
let unselectedColor = UIColor.cyan

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: unselectedColor,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham-Book", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedColor,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham-Book", size: 10)!], for: .selected)

if let items = self.tabBar.items {
    for item in items {
        if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.withRenderingMode( .alwaysOriginal )
            item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagename)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

After `viewDidLoad`:

```
   override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

   if(item.title! == "title")
   {
    item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagname)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
    if(item.title! == "title")
    {
        item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagname)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
    if(item.title! == "title")
    {
        item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagname)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
    if(item.title! == "title")
    {
        item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagname)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
    if(item.title! == "title")
    {
        item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "(Imagname)-a")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }

}
```

in view did load method you have to set the selected image and other image are showing with RenderingMode  and in tab bar delegate methods you set the selected image as per title

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift 4.0**, it's now changed as:

```
tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .selected)
```

You don't have to subclass the UITabBarItem if your requirement is only to change the text color. Just put the above code inside your view controller's `viewDidLoad` function.

For global settings change `tabBarItem` to `UITabBarItem.appearance()`.

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 4.2:**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

Comment: I put it into AppDelegate, under func application Works great!

Answer (score 3):

you can set tintColor of UIBarItem :

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.magentaColor()], forState:.Normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also do by this way:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {  
  if let items = self.tabBar.items {
    for item in 0..<items.count {
      items[item].image = items[item].image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            items[item].selectedImage = items[item].selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
```

Optional:

```
 UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

This Code works for **Swift 4** if you want to change the image of `Tab Bar Item` when pressed.
Copy and paste in the first `viewDidLoad` method that is hit in the project

```
   let arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState:[String] = ["Image1Color", "Image2Color","Image3Color"]
   let arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState: [String] = ["Image1NoColor","Image2NoColor","Image3NoColor"]


    print(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.count)

    if let count = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.count {
        for i in 0...(count-1) {
            let imageNameForSelectedState   = arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState[i]
            print(imageNameForSelectedState)
            let imageNameForUnselectedState = arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState[i]
            print(imageNameForUnselectedState)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[i].selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageNameForSelectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[i].image = UIImage(named: imageNameForUnselectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Year: 2020 iOS 13.3

#### Copy below codes to *AppDelegate.swift* -> *func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

```
//Set Tab bar text/item fonts and size
let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 12.0)!]
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)
//Set Tab bar text/item color
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(named: "YourColorName")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support iOS 13 and above please try this code, because the way to set UItabBar is totally changed from iOS 13.

```
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            
//            appearance.backgroundColor = .white
            appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            appearance.shadowColor = .white
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .gray
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
//            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .yellow
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .systemPink
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]
            
            // set padding between tabbar item title and image
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            // set padding between tabbar item title and image
            UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink], for: .selected)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html).

Each tab bar item has a title, selected image, unselected image, and a badge value.

Use the Image Tint (selectedImageTintColor) field to specify the bar item’s tint color when that tab is selected. By default, that color is blue.

Comment: The link is dead (404)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5:

```
let homeTab = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_FROM_ASSETS")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), tag: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.3

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.tabBarItem.title = "sample"
vc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
vc.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        
// for text displayed below the tabBar item
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode 13.0 you have options to set this color on the UI too:
Select the tab bar, then in the Inspector customize both Standard and Scroll to Edge Appearance, and below this items you will find a Stacked and Inline customization options. If you select custom, then you will have the "Title Color" setting. You have to set them all (4).

[image: Xcode inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new UITabBarController reference to the project.Next create a reference of UITabBar in this controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var appTabBar: UITabBar!
```

In its **viewDidLoad()**, simply add below for **title text color**:

```
    appTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.scandidThemeColor()
```

**For image**

```
    tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "FirstTab", image: UIImage(named: "firstImage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "firstSelectedImage"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your TabbarViewController and in ViewDidLoad put this code:

```
 [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor darkGreyColorBT]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor nightyDarkColorBT]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    self.tabBar.items[0].image  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-pack off@3x.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBar.items[0].selectedImage  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-pack@3x.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBar.items[1].image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-sleeptracker off@3x.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBar.items[1].selectedImage  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-sleeptracker@3x.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBar.items[2].image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-profile off@3x.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBar.items[2].selectedImage  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic-profile@3x.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

This is the simplest working solution I have

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 14/iOS 16, in your **UITabBarController** subclass, you simply set the **tintColor** and **unselectedItemTintColor** properties of **tabBar**:

```
tabBar.tintColor = 'some UI color'
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = 'some UI color'
```