# Customizing text color AND font of UITabBarItem causing weird result in swift

Tags: swift, fonts, ios9, uitabbaritem

I am trying to change the text of my `UITabBarItems` and have used questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117069/changing-tab-bar-item-image-and-text-color-ios). The second answer works great for me unless I try to adjust the font of the `UITabBarItem`. This snippet produces the expected results of the selected text being white and the unselected item being light gray:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()], forState:.Normal)

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

[image]

However, if this is added :

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 13)!], forState: .Selected)
```

[image]

For some reason the text becomes black when it is both selected and unselected and the font remains unchanged.

Weirdly enough if I change `.Selected` to `.Normal` in the last snippet, then the selected text turns white and the text is made to match the font in the code.

[image]

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 13)!], forState: .Normal)
```

This is almost perfect however the unselected text is now unchanged. Im not sure if I am doing something wrong or this is a bug, but if there are any other methods to completing this task, I would love to hear it.

Based on dfri's comments I have tried this:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 13)!]], forState:.Selected)

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 13)!]], forState:.Normal)
```

and now the app is crashing. The error says :

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa6d9461ef0

which does not make any sense to me

Comment: @dfri this causes the same results as the second snippet where the text is always black

Comment: @dfri I think i interpreted your comment correctly where I should try setting both the color and the font at the same time however, when I tried that it crashes the app. Check the updated question. The same result occurred when the attributes were stored in an outside array

Comment: @dfri that did it! thanks so much

Comment: That's great, happy to help!

Comment: I want make the font Bold. how could I do that? anyone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following

```
let colorNormal : UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let colorSelected : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
let titleFontAll : UIFont = UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 13.0)!

let attributesNormal = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : colorNormal,
    NSFontAttributeName : titleFontAll
]

let attributesSelected = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : colorSelected,
    NSFontAttributeName : titleFontAll
]

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributesNormal, forState: .Normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributesSelected, forState: .Selected)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the font for me for `.selected` state.

Comment: @AbbasAngouti make sure you add this in your AppDelegate class. Should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 10 and above, you only need to change the font for .normal, this will affect fonts on both selected and unselected items.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.myMediumFont(withSize: 10)], for: [.normal])
```

Also, you can set the tintColors without using .setTitleTextAttributes like so:

```
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using iOS 15.5. I was trying to change font size of tab bar item title with all the solutions provided above. However nothing worked for me.
Then I tried to modify **stackedLayoutAppeaarance** under **UITabBarAppearance** instead of **UITabBar.appearance()**.

What has worked for me is the following code:

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)]
```