# Is it possible to change a UITabBarController text color after it's been loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to change the `UITabBarControllers` text color after it's been loaded based on the users actions.

I can call this, and it changes the font and color correctly when it launches.

```
 let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
 let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 12)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]
 appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

When I try to call this anytime after the app has fully launched though, nothing happens.

Is this possible, or is it a one time thing you can do at launch?

Comment: Can you check with     `UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Selected)`    or for Normal state do `.Normal`

Comment: Or check with `tabBarController.tabBar` tintColor

Comment: You should try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117069/changing-tab-bar-item-image-and-text-color-ios

Comment: Setting the tint color works that way, but I don't want to change the tint color, I want to change the normal font color. 

I tried UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .normal) which does nothing for .normal and .selected when it's called after it's loaded.  It does work pre-loaded.

I'll take a closer look at that stack link, but all of that seems to be about setting it up before it loads or dealing with the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if i iterate over all the items and set them manually it works.  I then need to re-set the selected items color.

Still not sure why the other way won't work?

```
for myItem in (tabBar.items)! {
    myItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
}

tabBar.selectedItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green], for: .normal)
```